# How can I elegantly make an object from names to indices from a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I want to transform

```
myArr = ["Abel","Bella","Corey"]
```

into

```
myIndex = {"Abel": 1, "Bella":2, "Corey":3}
```

(I know I can do `.indexOf` but I want to make an efficient lookup dict)

Naively I'd do it like this:

```
myIndex = {}
for(var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++){myIndex[myArr[i]] = i;}
```

But I feel like I should be able to do it with map. Can I pass the index somehow with map?

Comment: Pretty sure the result of `map` is always an array, not an object.

Comment: You're correct, but you can initialize and empty object and modify with side effects within the map (though that's not necessarily elegant)

Comment: Sure you could, but why would you want to?  You're creating a pointless array (the output of `map`) just to use map instead of `for` or `forEach`?

Comment: FYI, your `myIndex` data structure is often called a "map" because it "maps" a key to a value.  Your naive implementation for doing the conversion from array to object is as good as any.  No real reason to do it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a good fit here as map returns an array, you can use [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
var myArr = ["Abel", "Bella", "Corey"];
var obj = {};
myArr.forEach(function (val, idx) {
    obj[val] = idx;
})
console.log(obj)
```

`.map()` handler will get the item indx as the second parameter

```
myArr.map(function (val, idx) {
    console.log(val, idx)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aVCxj/3/)

Comment: This is what I want. Foreach is good and passing index with second parameter is something I didn't know. Thanks!